# Spring @Transactional beahviour

Tags: java, spring, database, hibernate, transactions

It's normal when I create a method @Transactional with two entities, one for update and one for insert that Spring doesn't use the same transaction for update and insert?

```
@Transactional
public void myMethod(args...){
    Entity1 entity1 = entity1Repository.findById(args);
    entity1.setValue(args);
    Entity2 entity2 = new Entity2();
    entity2.setValue(args);
    entity2Respository.save(entity2);
}
```

In the hibernate log I see two transactions one for the findBy and update and other for the insert.

Comment: Look at the `entity2Respository.save` implementation. You will see that this method also annotated by `@Transactional`, hence one more transaction.

Comment: @SternK The default `propagation` is [`REQUIRED`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.8.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html#REQUIRED), which means *"Support a current transaction, create a new one if none exists"*, so the `save()` method will not create a new transaction, if `myMethod()` corrected started one. --- However, if the `@Transactional` annotation on `myMethod()` is ignored, somehow, the ones on the `findById()` and `save()` methods may cause the 2 transactions seen by OP.

Comment: There are multiple reasons why `@Transactional` might not be working. Did you check [all these questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=spring+%40Transactional+not+working) for potential solution before creating yet another question about `@Transactional` not working?

Comment: @SternK you are rigth, so this mean that it's imposible to manage with only transaction isn't it?

Comment: @JacoboGeada No, please see Andreas comments. By default the `@Transactional` propagation is `REQUIRED`, that means new transaction is not created if it already exists.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you call myMethod() from?
If it's from the same class it's like `@Transactional` annotation isn't even there because method is not called on spring proxy object and you would have separate transactions for update and insert.

Answer (score 0):

Using @Transactional(propagation.MANDATORY) from main method to the submethods I could use one transaction for all entities